# Nav bar header is not coming in the center

Tags: html, css, navbar

I wanted my heading should be in the center of the navbar. I have tried some code but that is not working.

```css
.navbar img {
  float: left;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  position: relative;
  top: -12px;
}

.navbar h1 {
  top: 18px;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: brown;
  text-align: center;
}

.navbar {
  min-height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default header">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">

      <h1>My heading</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

I have referred this link also: [How to center align text in navigation bar of website in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19056725/how-to-center-align-text-in-navigation-bar-of-website-in-css)

There they have mentioned it should be in `text-align: center`. But I have included already my script. Any input, please?

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43497560/center-bootstrap-navbar-title

Comment: @GBWDev is right. may be your other css files are affecting it

Comment: Your other css files affects the style of the `h1`. It has `margin-top: 20px` and `marginbottom: 10px` so it's not in the center.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `navbar-header` isn't taking up the full width because it has a `float: left` applied to it by default from Bootstrap. If you add a `width: 100%` property or a `float: none` property, you should see it center in the navbar.

```css
.navbar-header {
  width: 100%;
}
```

OR

```css
.navbar-header {
  float: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is in the center...? Perhaps its your other CSS file affecting it.

```css
.navbar img {
  float: left;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  position: relative;
  top: -12px;
}

.navbar h1 {
  top: 18px;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: brown;
  text-align: center;
}

.navbar {
  min-height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abel|Open+Sans:400,600" rel="stylesheet">


<nav class="navbar navbar-default header">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">

      <h1>My heading</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```